# Run Kinect 1.x sample on KFW2

Tags: c#, kinect

I moved to Kinect for Windows 2.0, and I want to run a sample from the 1.x series, and obviously Visual Studio shoves me 80++ errors.

Searching on the web was useless, I found no documentations for *porting* old code to 2.0, or at least, I wasn't able to find any good source.

Has anyone succeeded in running old examples on the new KFW2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API has certainly changed, you will have to create wrapper (adapter pattern) around sdk 2.0 or correct your code to use newer API. In every case you will have to alter our original code to some extend. Altho there are *some* similarities there is no simple "converter-like" solution.

Comment: Thanks, but that's less than reassuring! :) I have basically to start everything from scratch without almost any backward compatibility, and it kinda saddening... it's a complete waste of time.

Comment: Maybe you can start an opensource project with the solution for wrapping kinect 1 sdk in kinect 2. I can help you with that.

Comment: I don't know if that would be cost-effective: it seems to me that MS is quite clear that we should *not* use KFW1.x. What are other developers doing? I'm very new to Kinect.

Comment: Kinect SDK 2.0 more info available here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/